# How can i simplify an expression using the Real-Valued Root?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

My expression is

$$ f(x)= x\gamma\,(-1+\sqrt[3]{-1} \,-\sqrt[3]{-1^2}) $$

Simplifying using

```
FullSimplify[f(x)]
FullSimplify[Re[f(x)]]
```

returns a value of $0$

If i use Wolfram(online) and click " Use Real-Valued Root " it returns

$$-3x\gamma$$

Which is what i want.

I understand in this expression it is easy to do by hand but i would like to use a similar simplifying technique for larger expressions.

Thank you kindly for taking the time to help.

Edit

```
FullSimplify[(-EulerGamma + (-1)^(1/3) EulerGamma - (-1)^(2/3)
  EulerGamma) x ]
```

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica language is different from Wolfram Alpha language. The Wolfram Mathematica language uses `[]` for functions and not `()`. Try `[]` and see what happens when using the Wolfram Mathematica language.  The  Wolfram Alpha language uses AI to help understand the input.

Comment: Please provide *Mathematica* code for your function. Note that `f(x)` means the product of `f` with `x`.

Comment: apologies for not being specific enough , i have minor experience with Mathematica but understand some of its basic language , it is a question of how i can tell Mathematica to use the real-valued root rather than the complex one to simplify.

Comment: Use `CubeRoot` instead of raising to the 1/3 power.

Comment: Yes, `CubeRoot` or `Surd` more generally.